# Double Pointer char Operations

Tags: c, arrays, string, argv

Assume I have `char **argv`.

First, how can I print out all the strings in `argv`? I tried the following:

```
char *temp;
temp = *argv; // Now points to the first string?
while (temp != NULL) {
    printf("%s ", temp);
    temp++;
}
```

In here, when `temp` is incremented, it only skips one character. Why is that happening? I know that `argv` is an array that holds points. Each pointer, points to an array of `char*`. If so, why isn't this working? I know that since `temp` is of type `char`, incrementing that pointer would increment it by `1` char (or byte). If so, how can I increment the pointer into the next array and print that string out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It skips only one character because `temp` is a pointer to a `char`.  By adding one, you're telling the compiler to move the pointer on to point at the next `char` in memory.

`argv` is an array of pointers.  What you need to do is move on to the next *pointer* on each iteration.  Something like:

```
char **temp = argv;  // temp is a pointer to a *pointer*, not a pointer to a *char*
while (*temp != NULL) {
    printf("%s ", *temp);
    temp++;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to increment `argv`, not `*argv`. With a local copy, this looks like so:

```
for (char ** p = argv; *p; ++p)      // or "*p != NULL"
{
    char * temp = *p;                // now points to the first string!
    printf("%s ", temp);             // or just "printf("%s", *p);"
}
```

Comment: Is the last element of argv null? I would expect this to run off the end of the array.

Comment: @CollinHockey: Yes, the standard requires it.  See 5.1.2.2.1 of the C99 standard.

Comment: @CollinHockey: Going by the OP's abortive attempt I would assume so, and also because there's no other obvious termination condition in sight. Oli: the OP didn't say that we're dealing with the standard `main` argument, but let's all pretend we do.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Good to know.
I assumed he was using the standard argv/argc pair somewhere in main.

Comment: Nope not dealing with standard main argument, but it is NULL terminated.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to understand what `char** argv` is. It is an array of pointers to char. The pointers in this array don't necessarily reside anywhere near eachother in the address space. What you want is this:

```
char** temp;
temp = argv;
while(temp != argv + argc) {
    printf("%s ", temp);
    temp++;
}
```

You need to have a pointer to the first element of the array to pointers to char. Increment that instead.

Comment: There is no `argc`. It is not standard main argument.

Answer (score 0):

You have to increment `argv` not `*argv`. Note that if your `argv` is the parameter of the `main` function it is modifiable and you can use it like this:

```
    while (*argv++) {
        printf("%s\n", *argv);
    }
```

Comment: If he only needs to print the strings value, this is the most compact form.

Answer (score 0):

what you probably want to do is this:

```
char* a = argv[0];  // first arg
char* b = argv[1];  // second arg
char* c = argv[2];  // third arg
```

which is equivalent to this:

```
char* a = *(argv + 0);
char* b = *(argv + 1);
char* c = *(argv + 2);
```

which you would then want to generalise into a loop.